# Prove that $\prod_{\sigma \in Gal(K/F)}(x-\sigma(a))=min(F,a)^{n/r}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a galois extension of $F$ and let $a\in K$. Let $n=[K:F], r=[F(a):F], H=Gal(K/F(a))$. Let $\tau_1,\tau_2, \cdots \tau_r$ be left coset representatives of $H$ in $G$. Show that $min(F,a)=\prod_{i=1}^r(x-\tau_i(a))$[This part I have proved]
Conclude that $\prod_{\sigma \in Gal(K/F)}(x-\sigma(a))=min(F,a)^{n/r}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the product over $\sigma \in G$ into the the individual cosets of $H$, and use the fact that elements of $H$ fix $a$.

$\begin{align*}
\prod_{\sigma \in G} (s - \sigma(a)) &= \prod_{i = 1}^r \prod_{h \in H} (s - \tau_i h(a))\\
&= \prod_{i = 1}^r \prod_{h \in H} (s - \tau_i(a)) \\
&= \prod_{i = 1}^r (s - \tau_i(a))^{n/r} \\
&= min(F,a)^{n/r}
\end{align*}$